# Signal is assigned but never used. This unconnected signal will be trimmed

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx, spartan

To start with - I have three dimensional reg, assigned only in initial begin.

```
reg [4:0] PS[0:9];

PS[0] = 24; PS[1] = 10; PS[2] = 8; PS[3] = 8; PS[4] = 17;
PS[5] = 16; PS[6] = 4; PS[7] = 4; PS[8] = 16; PS[9] = 16;
```

At first i was trying to access bit like this (pc is my program counter):

```
if(PS[pc][4] == 0) Z1 <= 0;
else Z1 <= 1;
```

But optimization have been trimming my signals. Later I've found out that i need new reg to keep whole reg, then i can access bits. So I made this:

```
reg [4:0] tempPS;
```

[...]

```
tempPS = PS[pc];
Z1 <= tempPS[4];
```

My signals stopped to be trimmed, but now optimization wants to trim tempPS because:

Signal  is assigned but never used. This unconnected signal will be trimmed during the optimization process.

Well - as pc is changing, tempPS is used, I don't know what exactly this error means, how can I fix it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: are you sure it is 3-dimensional? `reg [4:0] PS[0:9];` PS is 5 bits wide and 10 locations deep. Not sure if your addressing is the correct way around but `PS[pc][4]` is accessing one bit, is this what you intend?

Comment: You say: "Well - as pc is changing, tempPS is used". Writting a value to tempPS is not "using" the variable. To prevent this signal to be trimmed, it must be written to and read from somewhere else in your module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*Signal is assigned but never used*" means that in your design there is a variable which receives a value, that is, there is a write access to the flip flops of that variable, but the value it receives is never used in any other part of the design. That is, there's no read access to that flip flop.

So you have to check whether yout `tempPS` register is used as a RHS in a Verilog expression, or their pins are outputted to the TLD ports of your design.

In your design, the only part of `tempPS` that is both assigned and read is `tempPS[4]`. The rest of the bits of that register are never read so it's pontless to store a value in them (nobody will read them!).

And like a chain reaction, if values stored in `PS` memory are transfered only to `tempPS`, and the only part of `tempPS` that is actually used is `tempPS[4]`, that means that the only part of `PS` that will be actually used is bit 4 of all 10 values, so expect the synthetizer to trim `PS[0]`, `PS[1]` and `PS[2]` of all 10 values of `PS` as well.

---

In other words:

- If a `reg` is read from (used on the right side of a expression, or connected to an output port which in turn is connected to somwhere else) but is not written to, that `reg` will be converted to a constant with value equal to the one that was initialized to in an initial block. Electronically, a constant is a signal with bits tied to `VCC` or `GND` to implement `1` or `0`.
- If a `reg` is written from (used on the left side of a expression, or connected to an input port which in turn is connected to somewhere else) but is not read from, that `reg` will be trimmed. The logic behind this decission is: *"if nobody cares about what my value is, it doesn't matter if I exist or not"*

Trimming occurs in cascade: if you have a code like this:

```
reg r0=0,r1=0,r2=0,r3=0;
always @(posedge clk) begin
  r1 <= r0;
  r2 <= r1;
  r3 <= r2;
end
```

Then:

- `r0` will be converted to a constant, because it is not written to, but it seems that it is read from (first non blocking assignment)
- Both `r1` and `r2` seem to be read from and written to, so the synthetizer should preserve them, but...
- Here comes `r3`: it is written to, but nobody reads its value, so the synthetizer trimes it. As a consequence of this, the third assignment (`r3 <= r2`) is deleted, and hence, `r2` is no longer used in the RHS of a expression (i.e. nobody reads its value), so it is trimmed too. Because of that, the second assigment (`r2 <= r1`) is deleted. Once again, `r1` is no longer read from so it is trimmed, making the first assignment (`r1 <=`r0) useless, thus causing `r0` to no to be read from, and hence, trimmed too. So our `always` block contains no code, so the synthetizer deletes it, leaving a completely empty circuit as result .

Comment: I've pasted only part of code:

    tempPS = PS[pc];

    Z1 = tempPS[4];
    Z2 = tempPS[3];
    Z3 = tempPS[2];
    t1 = tempPS[1];
    t2 = tempPS[0];

It's used only as helper - so I can read bits from 5-bit PS. All 5 bits are used, and all 10 states are used ;/ On simulation it works as it should be working. But during the synthezis this signal is trimmed and everything goes bad...

Comment: And what do you do with Z1, Z2, Z3, etc? If they are not used anywhere within your design, they will be trimmed, and hence, all bits from tempPS.

Comment: Z1, Z2, Z3 are my outputs - as for now, durign tests they have constraints for leds. t1 and t2 are setters for my timer, like:

if(t1)
begin
    time1 = 360;
    rst = 1;
end

Comment: Then post complete code, or a complete example, so we can see when and how registers are used

Comment: Cannot compile it. It says that timer is not defined.

Comment: I've figured out what timer might do and designed one myself, as this:
`module timer (
   input clk, 
   input rst, 
   input [26:0] time1, 
   output pulse);
   
   reg [26:0] t = 26'h0000000;
   assign pulse = (t == time1)? 1'b1: 1'b0;
   always @(posedge clk) begin
      if (rst)
         t <= 26'h0000000;
      else
         t <= t + 1;
   end
endmodule`. Then I've synthetized your design and it only has trimmed some flip-flops in time1 because you hace defined it with 27 bits but you only modify some of them. The rest are tied to a default value of 0. Z1, Z2, etc, have not been trimmered.

Comment: It haven't trimmed tempPS? That's the problem in my case - i'm using Xilinx Spartan 3-AN and Xilinx ISE Design Suite 14. Here's my timer:

http://pastebin.com/Kze3meMa

Comment: Weird... I have similiar one but i have one additional line. http://pastebin.com/5uYK8G9n WARNING:Xst:646 - Signal <tempPS> is assigned but never used. This unconnected signal will be trimmed during the optimization process. How is it even possible?

Comment: I made a change in your source: all assignments within a clocked always should be non-blocking assignments ( `<=` instead of `=` ). Try that.

Comment: Well, it stopped to trim tempPS, but it's not working as it should be when i'm using non-blocking assignments. After x1 is 1 it should be switching Z1 and Z2 for some time - while i'm using blocking assignments it works perfectly.

Comment: I've made pulse last for one tick longer and now it works like a charm. Thanks for amazing help.